# Error Filter Failed - Ricoh MP C2003

Tags: mac, printing, printer, network-printer

At the office we have a Mac mini that shares all printers. I do not think the error is Mac related. I have every printer working. Printing can be done from all devices. Mac, Windows, Linux.

There is one printer I can not get to work properly. The Ricoh MP C2003.
I can find the printer in the CUPS Administration page.

I have the right PPD file. Can select it and change settings of the printer. But when I print a test page it says: Printer stopped: "Filter failed"

Does someone have a great idea how I can fix this?

This is the error log:

```
E [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] The following messages were recorded from 15:43:42 to 15:43:43
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Adding start banner page "none".
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Adding end banner page "none".
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] File of type application/vnd.cups-banner queued by "admin".
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] hold_until=0
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Queued on "Congres" by "admin".
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] time-at-processing=1516200222
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] 3 filters for job:
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] cgbannertopdf (application/vnd.cups-banner to application/pdf, cost 33)
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] cgpdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 25)
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] foomatic-rip (application/vnd.cups-pdf to printer/Congres, cost 0)
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] job-sheets=none,none
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] argv[0]="Congres"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] argv[1]="351"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] argv[2]="admin"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] argv[3]="Test Page"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] argv[4]="1"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] argv[5]="job-uuid=urn:uuid:ae439d39-7165-395d-4093-ee4a40998d03 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1516200222 time-at-processing=1516200222"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] argv[6]="/private/var/spool/cups/d00351-001"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[0]="<CFProcessPath>"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[1]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/private/var/spool/cups/cache"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[2]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[3]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/doc/cups"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[4]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[5]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/private/var/spool/cups"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/libexec/cups"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[7]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/private/etc/cups"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[8]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/private/etc/cups"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[9]="HOME=/private/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[10]="PATH=/usr/libexec/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[11]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@mdm.hotelcasa.nl"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[12]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.2.5"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[13]="TMPDIR=/private/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[14]="USER=root"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[15]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[16]="CUPS_SERVER=/private/var/run/cupsd"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[17]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[18]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[19]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[20]="LANG=en_US.UTF-8"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[21]="APPLE_LANGUAGE=en-US"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[22]="PPD=/private/etc/cups/ppd/Congres.ppd"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[23]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[24]="CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-banner"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[25]="DEVICE_URI=ipp://192.168.11.63:631/ipp/print"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[26]="PRINTER_INFO=Congres"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[27]="PRINTER_LOCATION=Zalen"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[28]="PRINTER=Congres"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[29]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[30]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[31]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-pdf"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] envp[32]="AUTH_I****"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Started filter /usr/libexec/cups/filter/cgbannertopdf (PID 2701)
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Started filter /usr/libexec/cups/filter/cgpdftopdf (PID 2702)
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Started filter /usr/libexec/cups/filter/foomatic-rip (PID 2703)
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Started backend /usr/libexec/cups/backend/ipp (PID 2704)
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Getting input from file 
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] foomatic-rip version 4.0.6.230 running...
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Parsing PPD file ...
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option OptionTray
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option ShiftTray
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option InnerTray2
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option ExternalTray
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option Finisher
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option ColorModel
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option GSCmdLine
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option JCLDatamode
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option Resolution
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option GSResolution
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option JCLResolution
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option Duplex
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option GSDuplex
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option JCLDuplex
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option Collate
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option RICollateKind
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option PageSize
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option InputSlot
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option RIPrintMode
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option RPSBitsPerPixel
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option RPSBlackOverPrint
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option MediaType
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option OutputBin
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option StapleLocation
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option RIPunch
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option RIBannerPagePrint
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option RIBannerPageInputSlot
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option RIBannerPageMediaType
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Message catalog filename is \"/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/cups_apple.strings\".
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option PaperDimension
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option ImageableArea
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option JobType
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Sending stdin for job...
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Looking up \"192.168.11.63\"...
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option Password
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] 192.168.11.63=192.168.11.63
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option UserCode
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Added option Font
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] cgpdftopdf - opened PPD file \"/private/etc/cups/ppd/Congres.ppd\"...
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] cgpdftopdf: PreferredRotation = -90
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] cgpdftopdf - NO filtering is needed; passing data through.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Parameter Summary
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] -----------------
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Spooler: cups
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Printer: Congres
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Shell: /bin/bash
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] PPD file: /private/etc/cups/ppd/Congres.ppd
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] ATTR file: 
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Printer model: Ricoh MP C2003 PXL
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Job title: Test Page
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] File(s) to be printed:
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] <STDIN>
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Ghostscript extra search path (\'GS_LIB\'): /usr/share/cups/fonts
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Printing system options:
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Pondering option \'job-uuid=urn:uuid:ae439d39-7165-395d-4093-ee4a40998d03\'
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Unknown option job-uuid=urn:uuid:ae439d39-7165-395d-4093-ee4a40998d03.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Pondering option \'job-originating-host-name=localhost\'
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Unknown option job-originating-host-name=localhost.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Pondering option \'date-time-at-creation=\'
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Unknown option date-time-at-creation=.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Pondering option \'date-time-at-processing=\'
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Unknown option date-time-at-processing=.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Pondering option \'time-at-creation=1516200222\'
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Unknown option time-at-creation=1516200222.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Pondering option \'time-at-processing=1516200222\'
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Unknown option time-at-processing=1516200222.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Options from the PPD file:
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] ================================================
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] File: <STDIN>
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] ================================================
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Message catalog filename is \"/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/cups_apple.strings\".
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] load_banner(filename=\"/private/var/spool/cups/d00351-001\")
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] hrDeviceDesc=\"RICOH MP C2003\"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] prtMarkerColorantValue.1.1 = \"black\"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] prtMarkerColorantValue.1.2 = \"other\"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] prtMarkerColorantValue.1.3 = \"cyan\"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] prtMarkerColorantValue.1.4 = \"magenta\"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] prtMarkerColorantValue.1.5 = \"yellow\"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] ATTR: marker-colors=#000000,none,#00FFFF,#FF00FF,#FFFF00
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] ATTR: marker-names=\'\"Zwarte toner\"\',\'\"Verbruikte toner\"\',\'\"Cyaan toner\"\',\'\"Magenta toner\"\',\'\"Gele toner\"\'
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] ATTR: marker-types=toner,waste-toner,toner,toner,toner
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] ATTR: marker-levels=20,0,20,20,100
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] new_supply_state=0, change_state=ffff
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -developer-low-report
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -developer-empty-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -marker-supply-low-report
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -marker-supply-empty-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -opc-near-eol-report
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -opc-life-over-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -toner-low-report
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -toner-empty-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -waste-receptacle-almost-full-report
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -waste-receptacle-full-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -cleaner-life-almost-over-report
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -cleaner-life-over-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] new_state=0, change_state=ffff
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -media-empty-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -door-open-report
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -media-jam-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -input-tray-missing-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -output-tray-missing-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -marker-supply-missing-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -output-area-almost-full-report
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] STATE: -output-area-full-warning
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Page = 595x842; 12,12 to 583,830
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] backendWaitLoop(snmp_fd=7, addr=0x7fd2505015e8, side_cb=0x1055b5ba1)
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] align for banner 1.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] align for banner 1.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Filetype: PDF
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Driver does not understand PDF input, converting to PostScript
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Storing temporary files in /private/var/spool/cups/tmp
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] PID 2702 (/usr/libexec/cups/filter/cgpdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] PID 2701 (/usr/libexec/cups/filter/cgbannertopdf) exited with no errors.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Starting process \"pdf-to-ps\" (generation 1)
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Cannot process \"<STDIN>\": Unknown filetype.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] pdf-to-ps exited with status 127
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Process is dying with \"Could not print file <STDIN>
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] \", exit stat 2
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Cleaning up...
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] PID 2703 (/usr/libexec/cups/filter/foomatic-rip) stopped with status 2.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] PID 2704 (/usr/libexec/cups/backend/ipp) exited with no errors.
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] End of messages
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] printer-state=3(idle)
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] printer-state-message="Filter failed"
D [17/Jan/2018:15:43:43 +0100] [Job 351] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Comment: You have a double negative in your second sentence. I assume it should be " I do not think the error *is* Mac related."

Comment: What protocol are you using to print to on the machine? Are you using LPD or IPP or something else? Also, there's a generic PCL driver bundled with the 2 or 3 most recent macOS releases (black & white only); do you get anything different happen when you use that?